# Google apps script no access via sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some google scripts bound to a google sheet...they are deployed as webapp and anyone even anonymous.
Now when i click on Tools Script Editor in the sheet - I get an error no permission to access

You need permission -Want in? Ask for access, or switch to an account with permission. Learn more

but I am the owner of this account and I only created the script.

I can then access the scripts only via script.google.com and not via the spreadsheet.

This behaviour started just today .

Has google changed anything

Comment: Did you try to opening the same script in sheet by logging in through incognito mode ?

Comment: yep tried this -still same issue- no permission when I try to open the script via tools-script editor in the sheet

Comment: I had the same thing happen today and it fixed itself.

Comment: In the meantime you can gain access to the Scripts via your GSuite Developer Hub